# É necessário ativar o Cross-Origin Requests para ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Eu fiz uma aplicação de teste, onde aponto para uma web api que está online,  o endereço desta api funciona e retornar os dados se for postada na URL browser, ela faz um GET.
Na aplicação de teste eu tenho:

```html
<Div>
    <Select id="method">
        <Option value="get"> GET </option>
        <Option value="post"> POST </option>
        <Option value="put"> PUT </option>
    </Select>
         
    <Input type="button" value="Experimente" onclick="sendRequest()" />
    <Span id='value1'>(Resultado)</span>
 
</Div>
 

@section scripts {
    <script>
    // TODO: Replace with the URL of your WebService app
        var serviceUrl = ‘enderecoapi';
 
    function sendRequest() {
        var method = $('#method').val();
 
        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: serviceUrl
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#value1').text(data);
        }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#value1').text(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
        });
    }
    </script>
}
```

Não está me retornando os dados, inspecionei os dados e não retornar erro, apenas “XHR finished loading: GET”

Comment: Não sou perito em ASP.net @itasouza, mas sim, o servidor (quem serve) tem que permitir executar uma ação. A diferença de funcionar o GET pelo Browser e não por Ajax é que Ajax faz um XMLHttpRequest e essa informação vai no header da requisição. Portanto, a única forma elegante e correta é a aplicação ASP permitir Cross-Origin.

Comment: @LucasCosta, eu vou pesquisar sobre isso

Answer (score 1):

Olá, 
Se a API estiver em outro domínio, que não o da aplicação ,  você terá de ativar o cross origin(CORS) na API.

Por exemplo:
Se tiver a aplicação estiver em:**dominio.com**,
E a api em **dominio.com/api** você não precisará de cross origin

Agora se a aplicação estiver em:**meudominio.com**, 
E a api em **outrodominio.com**, é preciso habilitar o cross origin.

Não conheço .net, mas imagino que esse link sirva:

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Mais específicamente essa parte:

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace WebService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // New code
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

e essa:

using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

```
namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods not shown...
    }
}
```

No parâmetro origins você deverá colocar o endereço da aplicação que quer chamar a api. Para testes você pode colocar "*", mas não envie para produção

Abraço!